# Batch Error: Using $this when not in object context, so Can I call batch method in non static way?

Tags: forms, batch-operations

## The existing code

when a form is submitted I execute this batch :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $node_titles = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'node5'];

  $batch_builder = (new BatchBuilder())
    ->setTitle(t('Processing Batch'))
    ->setInitMessage('Batch is starting')
    ->setProgressMessage('Processed @current out of @total.')
    ->setErrorMessage('Batch has encountered an error');

  $batch_builder->addOperation(['Drupal\drupolo_batch\Controller\NodeUpdate','run'], $node_titles);

  batch_set($batch_builder->toArray());
}
```

The `batch_set()` method always calls a static method, and this works as expected:

```php
public static function run($title, $etm, &$context) {
  $node_storage =  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

  $values = [
    'type' => 'article',
    'title' => $title,
  ];
  $node = $node_storage->create($values);
  $node->save();
  $context['results'][] = '';
}
```

## Problem

I want to access the injected service: `$this->entityTypeManager`, so I have tried to use a non-static method to access the injected entityTypeManager service.

When I try this:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\drupolo_batch\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;

class NodeUpdate {
  public $entityManager;

  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityManager) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entityManager;
  }
   ....
  public  function run($title,$etm,  &$context) {
    kint($this->entityTypeManager); die();
  }
}
```

I get this error :

ResponseText: Error: Using **$this** when not in object context in Drupal\drupolo_batch\Controller\ **NodeUpdate::run()** (line 15 of NodeUpdate.php).

!! the method call is still static **::run()**

## Solution that doesn't work for me

1. I have declared my class as a service with the proper dependencies:

```php
services:
  drupolo_batch.node_update:
    class:  Drupal\drupolo_batch\Controller\NodeUpdate
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager']
```

2. In `addOperation` method I have passed my service

```php
$service = \Drupal::service('drupolo_batch.node_update');
$batch_builder->addOperation([ $service ,'run'], $node_titles);
```

3. This is called in a non-static way but I get this error :

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
AssertionError: **The container was serialized. in assert()** (line 28 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
assert(, 'The container was serialized.') (Line: 28)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container->__sleep()
serialize(Array) (Line: 89)
Drupal\Core\Queue\DatabaseQueue->doCreateItem(Array) (Line: 56)
Drupal\Core\Queue\DatabaseQueue->createItem(Array) (Line: 993)
_batch_populate_queue(Array, 0) (Line: 899)
batch_process() (Line: 63)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 593)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('codimth_batch_form', Array, Object) (Line: 321)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 91)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 38)
Drupal\webprofiler\StackMiddleware\WebprofilerMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

## Question

1. Is there any way to call the batch method non statically to access
   the injected services?
2. What is the cause of the previous error and how can I fix it?
3. Should I pass the services as parameters instead of injecting them into my service?

Comment: Why not use `\Drupal::service` in the static method itself? Otherwise the `drupolo_batch.node_update` service needs to be made serialisable so it can be stored in the database with the batch op.

Comment: I think error number for #3 is a result of having entityTypeManager be public. Try changing it to protected.

Comment: @Clive I prefer to inject the services for easy unit testing and also bc this service will be used by other services so thank you I will try to serialize the service,

Comment: You don't have to serialize the service yourself, you just need to make sure that it's serializable. As I said in my earlier comment, I believe that setting the entity type manager as public can cause your problem, as I believe it causes serialization errors.

Comment: @Jaypan I have already  make the entityTypeManager prop protected but that doesn't work,  stil have the same error,  anywhy thank you but I will juste use the satic method .

Comment: In that case, Clive's suggestion of using a static call from your static method is how you will need to proceed.